# Arrange the string in every possible correct alphabetical sequence of three characters

Tags: python-3.x

> write a python program to Arrange the string in every possible
>   correct alphabetical sequence of three characters

for example :

```
INPUT : "ahdgbice"
OUTPUT: {'abc', 'bcd', 'ghi', 'cde'}
```

Can anyone Suggest me a Optimised Method to do that I have tried and Was Successful in generating the output but I am not satisfied with my code so Anyone please suggest me a proper optimised way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a decent result:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> in_s="ahdgbice"
>>> in_test=''.join([chr(e) for e in range(ord(min(in_s)),ord(max(in_s))+1)])
>>> {s for s in map(lambda e: ''.join(e), (it.combinations(sorted(in_s),3))) if s in in_test}
{'abc', 'ghi', 'bcd', 'cde'}
```

How it works:

1. Generate a string that goes `abc..khi` in this case to test if the substring are in alphabetical order: `in_test=''.join([chr(e) for e in range(ord(min(in_s)),ord(max(in_s))+1)])`
2. Generate every combination of 3 letter substrings from a sorted `in_s` with `map(lambda e: ''.join(e), (it.combinations(sorted(in_s),3)))`
3. Test if the substring is sorted by testing if it is a substring of `abcd..[max letter of in_s]`

Answer (score 0):

Solution: It's not optimised solution but it fulfil the requirement

```
# for using array import numpy lib

import numpy as np

#input string 

str_1="ahdgbice"

#breaking the string into characters by puting it into a list.

list_1=list(str_1)

# for sorting we copy that list value in an array

arr_1=np.array(list_1)
arr_2=np.sort(arr_1) 

# some temp variables

previous=0
str_2=""
list_2=list()

#logic and loops starts here : looping outer loop from 0 to length of sorted array

for outer in range(0,len(arr_2)):

#looping inner loop from outer index value to length of sorted array


   for inner in range(outer,len(arr_2)):

        value=arr_2[inner]

    #ord() return an ascii value of characters

    if(previous is 0):
        previous=ord(value)

    #difference between two consecutive sequence is always 1 or -1 
    # e.g ascii of a= 97, b=98 ,So a-b=-1 or b-a=1 and used abs() to return absolute value

    if(abs(previous-ord(value)) is 1):
        str_2=str_2+value # appending character with previous str_2 values
        previous=ord(value)   # storing current character's ascii value to previous 

    else:
        str_2=value   # assigning character value to str_2
        previous=ord(value) # storing current character's ascii value to previous 

    # for making a string of three characters 
    if(len(str_2) == 3):
        list_2.append(str_2)

# Logic and loops ends here

# put into the set to remove duplicate values 

set_1=set(list_2)

#printing final output

print(set_1)
```

Output:

```
  {'abc', 'bcd', 'ghi', 'cde'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `itertool` module's `permutations` function to get a list of all three-element permutations of your input, and then for each result see if it is identical to a sorted version of itself.